# Why does computer "forget" root password sometimes?

Tags: login, root

There are a few times where my computer will "forget" my root password. This effects my ability to use `sudo` as well using the login manager (ie. locking the computer and trying the password there also fails).

Keep in mind, I am 100% confident that I'm not making a typo; I've typed it out to ensure I'm typing it correctly, copy-pasted it, even verified that I remembered the password correctly by using it on a different device that I know uses identical passwords.

I can fix it "easily" by resetting the computer (though it's obviously annoying). It's only happened two or three times in the past-year, but it's still a really odd thing to happen.

**Any idea why the computer "forgets" the root password?**

The only thing I can think of is a bit flip in memory, but that's assuming that the root password is stored in memory (not sure if that's true or not) and for the bit-flip itself to happen (which is exceedingly rare from what I can tell).

If distribution is of any consequence, I'm running Manjaro-i3.

Comment: Is it possible that something modifies `/etc/shadow` or `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: Maybe. The most recent one (a few minutes ago) was on a software update using `yay`. Said software update was building MPICH, which took about 15 or so minutes to do (at 100% CPU usage). I don't see why/how that process would be able edit those files.

Comment: You've set up `sudo` to use the *root* password?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I'm not sure. I may be conflating root password and the password I use to get root permissions.

Comment: If you're using `sudo`, you're supplying your login password. `sudo` remembers that you have authenticated for a while, and, for convenience, doesn't require reauthorization. If the time since your previous `sudo` command is greater than this time, `sudo` requires reauthorization. See `man sudoers`

Answer (score 0):

If your system "forgets" the `root` password, it means that something has written over the `root` password in `/etc/shadow`.  It's rare for any software (other than user-administration applications) to touch `/etc/shadow`.  I've never seen it.  Instead, I think it's worth clarifying when you may need to enter your root or user password.  Here's a brief explanation that might help:

For a basic install, you'll generally have two non-system users: `root` and yourself `james`.  Each non-system user has its own password.

- If you ever switch users (i.e. `su root` or `su james`), you need to enter the password of the user you are switching to.
- If you use `sudo`, you need to enter the password of the current user.  `/etc/sudoers` defines the rules about who you are allowed to pretend to be, but other users (including `root`) do not need to share their passwords with you.
- If you use pollkit/`pkexec` (often used by gui applications) a GUI dialog will appear and tell you which user you need to authenticate as.  If it says something like: "Enter the administrator's password", it's asking you for the `root` password, not your user's password.  To make it ask for your user's password, there needs to be some pollkit rules to define what your user is allowed to do (similar to `sudo`'s `/etc/sudoers`).

If you are sure that `/etc/shadow` is actually being changed without your authorization, that could be a sign of malice software which already has `root` privileges.